# pgfplots library `fillbetween` with table data creates strange x shapes

Tags: tables, pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to fill the area between my data and the x-axis using pgfplots and its library `fillbetween`. My two attempts are shown here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.13}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

Example using x-axis \\ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=A, ylabel=B]
        % data
        \addplot[name path=D] table [y=B, x=A]{dataB.csv};
        % x axis
        \path[name path=X]
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
        % fill between
        \addplot[gray!20] fill between[of=D and X];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Example using zero function \\ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=A, ylabel=B]
        % data
        \addplot[name path=D] table [y=B, x=A]{dataB.csv};
        % zero function
        \addplot[name path=N,domain=0:1]{0};
        % fill between
        \addplot[gray!20] fill between[of=D and N];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The attempts only differ in the way the x-axis is drawn. However, the results look off:

[image: Latex Output]

It looks like the x-axis is twisted (left and right are wrong). Does anyone have an idea how this can be resolved? Thanks in advance!

I reckon it could have to do with my data, so here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw/JGKmbtZ5

**Edit1**:
It seems to have to do with the data not forming a proper mathematical function, i.e. one x-value is assigned two (or more) y-values. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.13}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Not a mathematical function \\ \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=A, ylabel=B]
        % data
        \addplot[name path=D] coordinates {(0,1) (0,0.5) (1,2)};%table [y=B, x=A]{dataB.csv};
        % zero function
        \addplot[draw=none, name path=N,domain=0:1]{0};
        % fill between
        \addplot[gray!20] fill between[of=D and N];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latex Output]

**Edit2**:
The problem only seems to occur when the data starts with a straight line down. When the (mathematically) undefined data point appears in between start and end points, fillbetween works as expected:

```
\addplot[name path=D] coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (0.5,0.5) (2,1)};
```

[image: Latex Output]

I guess I'll have to insert an artificial data point to avoid this problem at the beginning of the graph.

Comment: This is actually a bug / missing support in pgfplots. I filed https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/195/ and will look into it. A work around is to add `reverse=true` to the option list after `fill between`.

Comment: Another workaround is to find a different line to `fill between` against. E.g. when I expected the filled area to be roughly triangular ◹ and using the vertical straight side gave me the X-shape, I used the horizontal straight side instead and `fill between` got it right.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
From new MWE is seems tha nature of data influence on function `fill between`. It seems that it expect that series of data don't have two different values of path `D` at the same `A`. For example, if in given MWE you change path `D` to

```
\addplot[name path=D] coordinates {(0,1) (0.000001,0.5) (1,2)};
```

You will get expected result:

[image]

With other words, I cant help you and will remove my answer after while.

Comment: The data is in the pastebin link ;-)

Comment: huh, I overlooked this link ... however used simple replacement of them was simpler to me :-). I will correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Zarko. Unfortunately, the problem remains when plotting with the data. My guess is that it has to do with the data. My data don't form a proper mathematical function. I.e., there are values which get assigned twice (when the graph drops straight down, e.g. at around 0 and 0.8).

Comment: Than please integrate your data to your MWE. I'm very sorry but haven't rnough time do this instead of you.

Comment: just edited my question with a simpler example ;)

Comment: You have right, your data confuse function `fill between`.  Cause is that two `B` values  are at the same `A`. For example, if you change coordinates to `coordinates {(0,1) (0.001,0.5) (1,2)}` than your MWE will work.